# OAuth Application not in Application Access Page (IBM Connections)

Tags: oauth, ibm-connections

A while back, I registered an application as an OAuth client using the steps described here: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/dx/Getting_Started_with_IBM_Connections_API_via_OAuth.  When using the application to run through the OAuth procedure to get the refresh token and access token, everything works out and a new refresh token and access token are granted.  When going to the Application Access page after the whole OAuth process, the application does not show up within the user's Application Access page.  Even now, after a few days of not going through the OAuth process, the refresh token can still be used to get a new access token and this in turn can be used to access the user's data.  What I want to know is why would this occur?  Did I miss some steps in the whole process or am I just not understanding the functionality of the Application Access page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to read up on the various oAuth settings that are possible with IBM Connections. 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYGQH_5.0.0/admin/admin/t_inst_installingandenablingoauthtai.dita

In particular you'll want to look at

> oauth20.issue.refresh.token   true    If set to true, clients will
>   receive a refresh token. If set to false, clients must request
>   authorization when the access token expires.

it means you should check your WebSphere Console and check the Trusted Authentication Interceptor settings and see if that is set to True or False.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this just raises more questions for myself as a developer: how are these values checked? Nobody in my company is sure. Also, the XML file located in the respective oauth20 folder does have the oauth20.issue.refresh.token set to true so if this value is propagated to the TAI then the value is already true. The registered application is a .NET web application; either that's the problem or there is an issue with the server itself. In the end, the application appearing on the page is not a big concern but it would be nice since then I can tell my boss that OAuth works.

Comment: I know the settings are loaded upon start of the application and may be cached for the life of the server. for further clarification, you may want to open a PMR